# Make user set self-taken image as background in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, background

I'm trying to develop an app, where I want it to be an opportunity for the user, to set the background image, to an self-taken image from the camera roll.

I've been googling a lot about this, but can't really find anything helpful.

Comment: This is a feature with deep system interaction. I highly doubt that this is possible from within a third-party application.

Comment: Do you want to set your app's background or the home screen's background?

Comment: I want to set the image as the background in my app. I've already made a function, that inserts the image from the camera roll, and then displays it in an image view. But as soon I restart the app, the image disappears.